# Ffmpeg create gif from images with fullPath

Tags: ffmpeg, gif, animated-gif

I need create gif from images in one line (without external file with list images). I dont understand how create if i have full paths ?

```
/home/userMo/test/dir1/4.jpg 
/home/userMo/pics/late/sada_342.jpg
```

I try by concat , but its dont work

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:/home/userMo/test/dir1/4.jpg|/home/userMo/pics/late/sada_342.jpg" -loop -1 out.gif
```

Comment: Where do you have the full paths? In a file? In a `bash` array? In two `bash` variables `p1` and `p2`?

Comment: in C# code ; array(string)

Comment: Huh? So why are you showing shell commands? And not tagging C# ?

Comment: i can create var in shell with array strings. I think irrelevant